# Magento 2.0.2 : How to update the title of "Privacy and Cookie Policy" link displays on footer store?

Tags: magento2, footer, link, magento-2.0.2

I would like to update the title of "Privacy and Cookie Policy" link displays on footer store (for example to translate this title in French).

The articles that I consulted talk about older versions of Magento thus not applicable for my problem.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to /your_theme/layout/default.xml .

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
    <referenceBlock name="privacy-policy-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My Privacy and Cookie Policy</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">my-privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: This is the content of my layout.xml :    

 <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher"        name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
  </referenceContainer>

I try to add your XML block without success !

Comment: I found ! it has to edit the C:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\module-cms\view\frontend\layout/default.xml + clear the cache of Magento (Admin)

Comment: awesome. glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the original answer is outdated. Here's where you'd put the new definition.

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Cms/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="privacy-policy-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Privacy Policy</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">privacy-policy</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```